# Flutter Image How starting a gif in next build at specific frame from where it left off in previous build

Tags: image, flutter, frame, assets, gif

I am trying to design a splash screen. There is a gif that shows in a splash screen. There is no problem of showing the gif.

The problem is that the gif restarts from first frame when the page rebuilds. In my use case, rebuild is expected since a provider listens a firebase user.

My question is that, how can i ensure the gif starts in next build at specific frame from where it left off in previous build.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:flutter_screenutil/flutter_screenutil.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';
import 'package:provider_architecture/provider_architecture.dart';

import 'package:myproject/core/viewmodels/startup_view_model.dart';

class StartUpView extends StatelessWidget {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    FirebaseUser user = Provider.of<FirebaseUser>(context);

    ScreenUtil.init(context, width: 411, height: 683, allowFontScaling: true);

    return ViewModelProvider<StartUpViewModel>.withConsumer(
      viewModel: StartUpViewModel(),
      builder: (context, model, child) {

      model.handleStartUpLogic(user);

      return Scaffold(
              backgroundColor: Colors.white,
              body: Center(
                child: Column(
                  mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Image.asset('assets/images/lock.gif', height: 100.h)
                  ],
                ),
              ),
          );
      },
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

That's interesting. My problem is the complete opposite of yours.
I want my gif to start from the beginning each time I load the gif, but it always starts at the frame that it left off last time.

```
return SafeArea(
  child: Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.black,
      appBar: AppBar(
        backgroundColor: Colors.black,
        title: Text(
          getImageName(),
        ),
        centerTitle: true,
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          
          children: <Widget>[
            Expanded(
              child: Image (
                height: height * 0.75,
                width: width * 0.75,
                image: AssetImage(getGuideImagePath()),
            )
            ),
```

However, for your problem, this implementation may help you.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xZ9vdVkI4Vc&feature=youtu.be

https://github.com/aliyigitbireroglu/flutter-image-sequence-animator/tree/master/image_sequence_animator